# Analyzing unbalanced/correlated data with classifier (behavioural biology example)

Tags: classification, random-forest

This is a real problem taken from behavioral biology. To make it simpler I will describe the specific problem instead of generalizing the description.

There are multiple sound recordings of two different call types emitted by a certain monkey species. Each recording was ran through an acoustic analysis program, which returns the values of about ten acoustic variables (e.g. recording_duration, peak_frequency, ...). The goal is to show, that the two call types differ in terms of their acoustic characteristics. However, the problem is that there are multiple recordings from individuals, from some more than from others, and some individuals are more often represented in callType1 than in callType2.

The plan was to use a classifier and show that it can distinguish the two call types based on the acoustic variables (i.e. perform better than chance). Thus, we don't want to include the ID of individuals as a predictor because that could improve the performance independent of acoustic characteristics. But not including it at all makes it problematic as well because in an unbalanced data set, the classifier could perform well simply by distinguishing the "voices" of the individuals which are unevenly distributed among the two call types. How would one consider the different contributions of individuals in such a case?

We were working with random forest (due to its independence of distributions) and were thinking of comparing a model including only ID as a predictor with a model including ID and all acoustic variables as predictors. The difference in performance between those two would have to be due to a difference in acoustic characteristics. Is this a valid approach? Or how would you approach that problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Approximately how many individuals (monkeys) and how many items (recordings) are in total?

Comment: In one dataset we have around 10 individuals (out of a population of around 30 monkeys in total) and around 120 recordings. In another dataset (different species) we have around 1000 recordings and 10 individuals.